# How to "flatten" Java package in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

In Eclipse I can flatten Java packages as the following:

[image]

How do I achieve the same result with Android Studio, which currently looks like below:
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Click in Settings icon in your "Project Bar" and choose "Flattern packages" (first option).

Comment: Thanks, also found that right click on the "Project Bar" would also show the "Flatten Packages" option.

Comment: Now the same feature is Termed as Compact Empty Middle Packages

Answer (score 1):

Just do something like that, actually I was struggling to find project bar

[image]