# Android Studio: separate package with subpackage

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

When you create a package in Android Studio, and then create subpackage, in a while it transforms to the form, you can see in attachment. So when I want to create another subpackage of `acctocard` with the help of

**right button click -> new -> package**,

my newly created package will be a subpackage of `acctocard.activities`.

Please, tell me, how to separate this packages, to have them displayed as a tree.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26953525/5192105 might help you out.

Comment: Yes, it is! Thank you so much!

Comment: you are gladly welcome.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

As [**Sachin Bahukhandi**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5192105/sachin-bahukhandi) adviced in the comments, I took a look at the [**post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26953402/how-to-flatten-java-package-in-android-studio/26953525#26953525).

So what you need to do, is to click **Project Bar** -> **Settings** and uncheck **Compact Empty Middle Packages** item.

[image]

Comment: when Flatten Packages item in ticked , Compact Empty Middle Packages item wont be visible

Answer (score 27):

Just do something like that, actually I was struggling to find project bar

[image]

Answer (score 4):

With the new IntelliJ UI (Beta in Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1)

[image]